# Devise error on sign_out No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an issue with the generated link :

```
<%= link_to('Logoff', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

is working with some users, and is returning

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

for others.  How that [GET] got in there, I have little idea...

Context: rails 3.2.16
application.js includes

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails.validations
//= require foundation
//= require_tree .
```

There is on jquery.js file in assets/javascripts
But there is a jquery.foundation.tabs.js in that folder.

I would rather not overwrite devise to allow get for destroy_user_session, as it is unrecommended.

All the answers on SO seem to have solutions which don't apply to this case...

***Update***

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users

namespace :admin do
  resources :users do
    collection do
      get :indexmio
      get :new_struttura
      get :new_admin_existing
      get :new_manager
      get :new_buyer
      get :new_buyer_existing
      get :new_manager_existing
      get :search_user
      get :result_user
      get :newsuser
      post :newsuser
      post :create_buyer
    end
  end
end
```

**Update 2**
The HTML code is also correct:

```
<a href="/users/sign_out" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Exit</a>
```

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: question updated with the relevant snippet of the file (it is rather long)

Comment: still no solution ? :-(

Comment: really no idea how this got solved to be honest; too far back in time.  I may have completely rolled back and re-installed/updated devise.

Answer (score 0):

Routing Error:

> No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"

To overcome this error, I changed the configuration in `config/initializers/devise.rb`.

Replace

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

with

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm too late, but this answer could help anyone who has the same problem and arrives to this post, too.

My solution was to change the "link_to" expression for a "button_to".

For any reason, rails pass link_to as GET, despite the :method passed.

Once you change for button, it follows the correct path.